# What am I doing wrong in my Accounts.createUser() configuration?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, google-account, createuser

I cant seem to get beyond the `Accounts.createUser()` line in my code. What's wrong?

I have:

```
Router.route('/', {
template: 'info',

   waitOn: function(){
       return Meteor.subscribe('userData');
   }

});
```

I am able to correctly see the results of `Meteor.user().services.google.email` in the browser console, which is my own email address since am logged in. Am also able to see the correct results for `Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken`.

And now for the code in subject:

```
Accounts.createUser({email: Meteor.user().services.google.email, password: Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken}, 
   function( error ){

   if(error){
       console.log(error.reason, 'Stranger Danger!');
   } else {
       var userId = Meteor.userId();
       console.log('Welcome!', 'success');

       Meteor.call( "initApiKey", userId );
   }
});
```

I cant seem to get beyond the `Accounts.createUser()` line. This is because, I fail to see any error messages, neither do I see the results of the `console.log()` which are the following functions/callbacks right in/after `Accounts.createUser()`.

Comment: Maybe you move the fallback for email from the method signature to the body and make a deeper check there

Comment: @Jankapunkt Am not too sure I understand what you mean. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You have a very complex auto value for email and password in the method signature. Why don't you just define it as `({ email, password })` and set the default in the method body where you can better trace errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do with that code.
It seams that you are trying to create an user account with an account that already exists.
With the code: `"email: Meteor.user().services.google.email, password: Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken"` seams like you logged in with a google account and you created the email and password. And as you said, you are already logged in with that account, so why would you want to create another acount based in an already existed one ??

If you could explain just a little bit further what you want to accomplish and post any errors or messages from the server-side console, i think would be esier to get what is going on. But I think that even if you get the code right, the `Accounts.createUser()` will not allow you to create two accounts with the same email and password.